# Change angular ui-grid csvExporter separator

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter, angular-ui-grid

I have a UI-Grid and i need to export it to CSV.
The problem is that the export has a comma (",") delimiter and for european versions of excel, I need a semicolon (";") delimiter. 
Is there any way i can set the csv delimiter in Ui-Grid, or to add an extra-line ("sep=;") to the csv file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your controller set the gridOptions [exporterCsvColumnSeparator](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions) variable to ";".

```
$scope.gridOptions.exporterCsvColumnSeparator = ';';
```

See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/features/exporter/js/exporter.js) at line ~210 for the relevant ui-grid/exporter.js code